# Make Parse Push Production Certificate - iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I am trying to make Push Certificate for Production so I am following the instructions here https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications, but in step 2, it says it should have a name of

```
Apple Production IOS Push Services
```

As I have changed this for production as it says to do in the note

"Note that you've just enabled Push Notification for your app in development    mode. Prior to releasing your application on the App Store, you will need to repeat steps 1 through 7 of this section, but select "Production Push SSL Certificate" in step 2 instead, as covered in Section 7."

But mine comes out as

```
Apple Push Services
```

And then in section 2 and 3 when I try to add my .p12 file it says

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I set up Push with Parse for Production.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Apple has changed the common name that they are embedding in the production push certificates that they issue.  This seems to be related to the deprecation of the older binary push service in favour of the new HTTP/2 service.

A certificate I issued earlier in the year has an common name of "Apple Production IOS Push Services: *appname*" while a certificate I just created has a common name of "Apple Push Services: *appname*".  Parse seem to have verification code that checks the certificate common name and this code does not accept the new name format.

There is nothing you can do on your side; Parse will need to update their code to accept the new certificate name.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating one of the new "Universal" certificates. Now you don't have separate certificates for Production and Development - just one certificate for both.

These certificates have a different name to the previous format. Perhaps the Parse control panel has not been updated to handle this yet.

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172015b

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you already created "Certificate from a Certificate Authority".

You need to open Keychain Access program. It is located in your Utilities folder in your Applications folder.

After you create your push certificate (the one you download in the developer portal), click it and install it into your keychain.

When you do, it will show up like this:

[image]

This is what Parse means in the instructions by it will have the name "Apple Production IOS Push Services"

Next, you will want to right-click your Production push certificate and click "Export Apple Production iOS Push Services":

[image]

Then it will take you to this screen to enter a password. DO NOT enter a password. Just click OK:

[image]

Then you will be asked to enter your system password. This is the same password that you use to login to your computer when you first turn it on. If you don't know it, then find out because you will need to know it to generate the p12 file.

Then name your P12 file:

[image]

This is the file that you will have to upload to Parse for production.

To create development P12, it is exactly the same. In fact, you should create your development p12 first, so you can test it on your development app.

Comment: Yes, first I create a `Production SSL Certificate` in the apple member center then I double click it, and I see it appear as `Apple Push Services: com.example.app` in Keychain Access not `Apple Production IOS Push Services` and then I do the export and get the error, I can't get `Apple Production IOS Push Services` in my keychain access

Answer (score 0):

Its because Apple announced a new HTTP/2 based provider API and simplified certificate management process thus changing the way these certificate were named (From Apple Production IOS Push Services to Apple Push Services), and Parse needed to update their system to allow for such certificate to be verified. Thats why you were getting this error. You should try again now, it seems to be working, mine just went through.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks I am still getting the same error, you just uploaded a new one and it worked?